# How to trigger Razor code-behind upon form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have a simple Razor form to create a `MatchViewModel`, which is a simple model with some properties. The view, `Create.cshtml`, didn't come with code-behind, so I made it myself manually (`Create.csthml.cs`).

I have followed some basic guides online for what to put in the code-behind - right now, I am just trying to hit my breakpoints in the code-behind when I submit the form in a browser, but it doesn't happen. I want the `OnPost()`-method to be triggered and call an endpoint in the controller.

Anyone have an idea, why my code-behind isn't triggered upon form submission? Do I need to specify something on the submit button in my Razor page (`Create.cshtml`)?

Code in `Create.cshtml.cs`:

```
public class Create: PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public MatchViewModel MatchViewModel { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        MatchController controller = new MatchController();
        controller.Create(MatchViewModel);
        return LocalRedirect("~/Match/Index");
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer in the meanwhile. Seems like I just missed an `asp-action="Create"` tag helper on my form submission `input` in the Razor page `Create.cshtml` to call the endpoint I wanted. All the code above is apparently unneccessary.